# How to set breakpoint on all the methods in a class in VS 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, breakpoints, visual-studio-debugging

How to set breakpoint on all the methods in a class in VS 2012.
Similar question is posted at [How do I set a breakpoint on every access to a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565694/how-do-i-set-a-breakpoint-on-every-access-to-a-class) 
but the solutions are not working with VS2012

Answer (score 0):

You may think of using [Debugger.Break](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break.aspx) and inject it in every method that you want to analyze.

Injection can be done: by hand, or by some mechanism like `AOP` programming.

Comment: I don't want to write code to add the breakpoint is there anything similar to Macros (VS2010) or maybe Addin.

Comment: @meetjaydeep: nor that I'm aware of. You may look on AOP. It's still the code, but written once :)

Answer (score 0):

You can position the caret within a class definition and call the following command (Language: C#) for [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) to set breakpoints on all the methods:

```
using EnvDTE;
using EnvDTE80;

public class C : VisualCommanderExt.ICommand
{
    public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
    {
        EnvDTE.TextSelection ts = DTE.ActiveWindow.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection;
        if (ts == null)
            return;

        EnvDTE.CodeClass c = ts.ActivePoint.CodeElement[vsCMElement.vsCMElementClass]
                    as EnvDTE.CodeClass;
        if (c == null)
            return;

        foreach(EnvDTE.CodeElement e in c.Members)
        {
            if(e.Kind== vsCMElement.vsCMElementFunction)
            {
                EnvDTE.TextPoint p = (e as EnvDTE.CodeFunction).GetStartPoint();
                DTE.Debugger.Breakpoints.Add("", p.Parent.Parent.FullName, p.Line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```