# Add breakpoint to c# class's every methods in VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, breakpoints

I have a class and I would like the debugger to stop whenever any of its method are called.

I tried using "`New function breakpoint`" but I couldn't find a working wildcard to use in "`Function Name`" (ex: I tried "MyNamespace.MyClass.*")

There are example for c++, but they don't seem to apply as-is for **c#** (or I'm missing something).

How can it be done?

Comment: Not really "helping", but if your class has so many methods that you ask for a tool or automated way to set breakpoints rather than simply set them manually, you might want to consider splitting that class up into several smaller ones. See also: [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/11625732/1132334, and https://stackoverflow.com/q/11625732/1132334 they suggest to just specify the class name, no wildcard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set a breakpoint on every access to a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565694/how-do-i-set-a-breakpoint-on-every-access-to-a-class), see latest comments on accepted answer.