# How do I add a breakpoint in Visual Studio for a whole class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, breakpoints

I want to add a breakpoint for a whole class and not only for a function, so I can see if the class will be used.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the constructors. If there are no constructors then add a parameterless constructor and put a breakpoint in there.

Comment: And one in each of the class's properties and methods.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set a breakpoint on every access to a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565694/how-do-i-set-a-breakpoint-on-every-access-to-a-class)

Answer (score 0):

Add a breakpoint to the constructor(s). If one doesn't exist create an empty one for this purpose. E.g.

```
public class Example
{
    public Example()
    { // Breakpoint goes here.
    }
}
```